# Why do my map labels disappear when publishing as a service on ArcGIS server?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, labeling, map-service

I am developing a map service, rather basic, with some polygons and labels. Surprisingly, when I deploy this service on the production server, the labels disappear (see [here](http://maratlas.discomap.eea.europa.eu/arcgis/rest/services/Maratlas/FishingQuotas/MapServer?f=jsapi)). I have a second local server - for this one, no problem: the labels are well and truly there.

Do you have an idea why my labels vanish that way? Is there some special tuning I should apply on the production server to have them back?

Many thanks for your help.

**Precision:** It happens with labels with field information. If I use a static text as a labels, the labels are there. The server seems unable to include object fields info within labels.

**Additional info:** Apparently, this is a well-known problem in ArcGIS server 10.1. See [this thread on ArcGIS forum](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/86616-Polygons-and-lables-disappeared-after-I-published-to-Server). No solution is known yet...

Comment: If you make a cache, do you see the labels in the cache?

Comment: Did you try fully qualifying your label expression ... FAOZONES.ICES instead of ICES ?

Comment: Yes, and it do not solve the problem neither.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem may be using the Maplex label engine. I have found that labels set using Maplex do not come through on a service or are highly unpredictable at best.

Try setting the labels the regular, non Maplex way. If you are already using regular labels, try adjusting the scale for label display.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have no idea which label engine is used... How to check and change it to the regular engine?

Comment: @julien Please check following link for Set default labeling properties.(http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00660000042z000000) save .mxd and then republish the map service.

Comment: OK, thanks. I checked, and I am already using the regular engine...

Comment: @julien How dense are your labels in the map document? I followed the link to your application and it looks like it would not have much detail, but I don't know what is being labeled. If you have a high density, try setting the labels to only display below a certain scale when the user zooms in.

Comment: The labels contain only 2 letters (country codes).

Comment: @julien Please confirm the following details: You are labeling a small selection (less than 20) of the countries of Europe using 2-letter abbreviation codes, using the standard label engine and not Maplex. You are not currently using a scale dependency labeling scheme. You can see the labels visible in your mxd (map document), but they do not come through when you publish it as a service, even after waiting for possible slow loading. Is that all correct?

Answer (score 3):

Would making them an annotation layer solve the issue? Seems like it would be worth a try, although I'm not sure how it robust it would be when you're zooming in and out of the service layer.

Comment: I prefer not to use annotations to keep the labels scale-dependant. Thanks anyway for the advice.